# nginx serving django static and media files 403 forbidden

Tags: django, nginx

First i try to find a solution from other questions, but they can't working for me, so i create a new one.

The detail are below:

1 I try change user in the nginx.conf

```
#user www-data;
user me;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
....
```

2 Add and link a conf on sites-available and sites-enabled

```
server {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *.mysite.com;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers X-Requested-With;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET,POST,OPTIONS;
    listen  80;
    server_name mysite.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/hitek.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/hitek.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8010;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ ^/media/  {
        #alias /var/www/html/mysite/media;
        alias /home/me/website/mysite/media;
        #alias /home/www-data/website/website/mysite/media;
        expires 1h;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/static/ {
        #alias /var/www/html/mysite/collected_static;
        alias /home/me/website/mysite/collected_static;
        #alias /home/www-data/website/website/mysite/collected_static;
        expires 1h;
        access_log off;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }
}
```

You can see 4 line comment, i try copy the collected_static and media folders this place ，but failure. Of course i change permission on this folders.

```
~/website$ ls -alt
drwxrwxrwx 8 me me 4096 Sep 11 14:43 mysite
drwxr-xr-x 6 me me 4096 Sep  8 14:30 ..
drwxrwxrwx 4 me me 4096 Sep  7 11:41 .
```

Who can answer it? thank.

Answer (score 0):

Add slash to the end of your path. Otherwise, Nginx is not able to find files.

```
alias /home/me/website/mysite/media/;
```